# Paypal Pass item sku and order reference id

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to send order to paypal using javascript api purchase_units, but when the paypal redirects to success page I get error unknown purchase_units. When I check the api calls in console I get exclamation mark near the call with purchase_units

Here is my code

```
 paypal.Buttons({
        env: 'sendbox',
        style: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            size:   'responsive',  
            shape:  'pill',        
            color:  'gold',        
            fundingicons: false,    
            tagline: false          
        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [ {
                reference_id: "PUHF",
                description: "Some description",
                custom_id: "Something7364",
                soft_descriptor: "Great description 1",
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: "200.00",
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "200.00"
                        }
                    }
                }, items: [{
                        name: "Item 1",
                        description: "The best item ever",
                        sku: "xyz-2654",
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "100.00"
                        },
                        quantity: "1"
                    }, {
                        name: "Item 2",
                        description: "Not bad too",
                        sku: "zdc-3942",
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "50.00"
                        }, quantity: "2"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    })}, onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('<?= $rootPath.URL['services']['orderGet'] ?>', {
                    method: 'GET'
                }
            ).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(res) {
                window.location.href = 'pages/success.php';
            });
        }

    }).render('#paypalCheckoutContainer');
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your purchase_units array into a full working HTML example (below, don't try to run it within StackOverflow) and did not have any issues.

Looking at the rest of your code, `env: sendbox` is a typo.  The onApprove section gave me trouble, I see there's PHP in there, but your code worked when removing the whole onApprove section -- so maybe try testing without that and then fixing it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- example from https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -->

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({


// You can find a working example purchase_units at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/
  purchase_units: [ {
                reference_id: "PUHF",
                description: "Some description",
                custom_id: "Something7364",
                soft_descriptor: "Great description 1",
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: "200.00",
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "200.00"
                        }
                    }
                }, items: [{
                        name: "Item 1",
                        description: "The best item ever",
                        sku: "xyz-2654",
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "100.00"
                        },
                        quantity: "1"
                    }, {
                        name: "Item 2",
                        description: "Not bad too",
                        sku: "zdc-3942",
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "50.00"
                        }, quantity: "2"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]

  ,
  application_context: {
    brand_name: "MyBusiness",
    /*shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'*/
  }


                }/*end of parameters to actions.order.create*/);
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: After running this code Order API return data as NULL on "checkout/orders/${order_id}/capture"  page

Comment: Is that an API capture? Have you tried a client-side javascript capture, just to see if there are any issues in contrast? Since your problem seems to be at the moment of capture, it'll be useful if you provided sample code for your capture, or a full example API request + response (including HTTP headers, not merely noting that data is NULL) for that situation.

Comment: I am just using the code from paypal git demo for server side integration https://demo.paypal.com/au/demo/download?capability=PayPalCheckoutServerSideV2&lang=PHP