# How to link order id for my ecommerce with react PayPal

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I have a react app that is linked with PayPal, the PayPal params do not expect me to pass my order id which is the identifier of which product user if paying for or at least I cannot seem to find which parameter I could pass there so that when IPN  brings back notification to my site then I can check out the user

My component looks like this

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={{
                    "client-id": PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
                }
                }>

                    <div>
                        <PayPalButtons style={{ height: 25 }}
                            createOrder={this.createOrder}
                            forceReRender={this.state.amount}
                            onApprove={this.paymentHandler}
                            onError={(error) => alert(error)} />
                    </div>
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

In the `onApprove` methods, I logged out the values and am getting an orderID param which does not seem to be part of the IPN returned values
the data from on Approve is like this

```
{'orderID': '6BX576974S2955109', 'payerID': 'NMWXFKW5ZW5EC', 'paymentID': None, 'billingToken': None, 'facilitatorAccessToken': 'toekn here'}
```

Could anyone help me out on this, like what param can I can use to pass my own value to the react-PayPal so that it is returned in the IPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [createOrder](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) function should call the PayPal SDK's `actions.order.create()` with an Orders V2 object. Available parameters are [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#orders-create-request-body).

If your own "order id" is unique --never before used for a successfully captured payment -- you can include it in the purchase_unit as the `invoice_id` parameter. Uniqueness is important since by default a duplicate (previously used/captured) invoice_id cannot be captured. Payers can see this invoice_id in their transaction's details.

If you want a field where you can store arbitrary data, use `custom_id`. Payers cannot see this value.

Comment: just tried this and am getting error, the component cannot be rendered `Bad object: {"purchase_unit": {
    "custom_id": 2
  }
}
Valid keys: [
  "buyer-country",
  "client-id",
  "commit",
  "components",
  "currency",
  "data-client-token",
  "data-csp-nonce",
  "data-order-id",
  "data-page-type",
  "data-partner-attribution-id",
  "debug",
  "disable-funding",
  "integration-date",
  "intent",
  "locale",
  "merchant-id",
  "vault"
]`

Comment: You're passing keys to the configuration. Don't do that.  Change goes in the createOrder function

Comment: okay just solved this... I was putting it in the wrong place was suppose to be in the createOrder  function.. thanks so much

Comment: Reading your question more closely, since your ID is for products rather than an "order id", you probably want to pass an items array rather than a custom_id , e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448758/paypal-pass-item-sku-and-order-reference-id